# EF Core group by and order by

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

I have an `emp` table with emps logged in I am trying to find current day when is the last time emp logged in below is the query I tried. group by each employees last login time and their details.

```
var result = this.EMP.Where(a => a.Time.Date == DateTime.Now.Date)
                     .GroupBy(a => a.empname)
                     .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(a => a.Time))
                     .FirstOrDefault();
```

I am trying order by descending and taking top 1 for each employee. I am getting error

> Collections in the final projection must be an 'IEnumerable

Can someone please help with this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this

```
var result = this.EMP
          .Where(a => a.Time.Date == DateTime.Now.Date)
          .GroupBy(a => new { a.empname, a.Time})
          .OrderByDescending(a => a.Key.Time))
          .Select(g => new 
             {
             Empname= g.Key.EmpName,
             Time = g.Key.Time
             }).FirstOrDefalt();
```

Comment: serge thanks this one gives first group I am trying with each employee with their last logintime so the group result will be EMP1 lastlogintime Desc,EMP2 lastlogintime  desc with their details whole row value for that particular employee.

Comment: Modified bit like below`var result = this.EMP
          .Where(a => a.Time.Date == DateTime.Now.Date)
          .GroupBy(a => new { a.empname})
          .Select(g => new 
             {
             Empname= g.Key.EmpName,
             Time = g.Max(x => x.Time)
             })` got the result with each person with their lastlogin time. Now I need to get the whole record now it gives the key coloumn personname,lastlogintime I need to get all coloumn values.

Answer (score 0):

This is how i solved

```
  var empids= this.EMP
              .Where(a => a.Time.Date == DateTime.Now.Date)
              .GroupBy(a => new { a.empname})
              .Select(g =>g.Max(x => x.ID)).ToList();
```

and in another query

```
var emprecords=this.EMP.Where(e=>empids.Contains(e.ID))
```

Comment: Not sure if there is way to make it as one query instead of splitting into two parts.